# Can't figure out how to properly format Makefile using SDL2. Undefined reference

Tags: c++, ubuntu, makefile, sdl-2

Makefile:

```
OBJS = Instantiation
Exec_NAME = Test.exe
CC = g++ #Compiler name
COMPILER_FLAGS = -c -g -Wall -std=c++11
#Issue exists somewhere in these next 3 lines, but what, how, why :( ?
INC = -I/SDLDEPS/include
LIB = -L/SDLDEPS/lib
LINKER_FLAGS = -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 #just saw this a lot, not sure what the mingw32 is.

#inclusion of $(INC) $(LIB) $(LINKER_FLAGS) not right
all: $(Exec_NAME)
$(Exec_NAME): $(OBJS).o
    $(CC) -o $(Exec_NAME) $(OBJS).o
Instantiation.o: $(OBJS).cpp
    $(CC) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) $(INC) $(LIB) $(LINKER_FLAGS) $(OBJS).cpp

clean:
        rm -f $(Exec_NAME) $(OBJS).o
rebuild:
        make clean
        make
```

---

```
//Main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Window.h"
//#include "SDLDeps/include/SDL.h"
#include "SDLDeps/include/SDL.h"
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0)
        std::cerr << "SDL Failed to initalize\n";
    else
        std::cout << "Great Success";
    Window window("TEST WINDOW");
    while(!window.isClosed()){
        window.pollEvents();
        window.Clear();
    }
    //std::string string = "";
    //std::cout << "HELLO PERSON What is your name?\n";
    //std::cin >> string;
    //std::cout << string << "!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
//Window.h I don't think Window.cpp is necessary as the issue is linking, I think.
#ifndef WINDOW_H
#define WINDOW_H
#include <string>
#include "SDLDeps/include/SDL.h"
//#include "SDL.h"
#include <iostream>

class Window {
private:
    std::string title;
    int width, height;

    bool closed;    
    
    bool init();

    SDL_Window* window;
    SDL_Renderer* renderer;
public:
    Window(const std::string&, int = 800, int = 600);
    ~Window();
    
    void pollEvents();
    void Clear() const;
    inline bool isClosed() { return closed; }
};
#endif // !WINDOW_H
```

---

```
//    Instantiation.cpp- just a file that includes files that I am compiling:
        #include "Window.cpp"
        #include "Main.cpp"
```

---

I am fairly new to doing linking and "advanced" things with makefiles. But hours of
googling I can't find out why I keep getting:
/mnt/c/users/nichorsin598/source/repos/Self/TestSDL/Window.cpp:13: undefined reference to `SDL_DestroyWindow' /usr/bin/ld: /mnt/c/users/nichorsin598/source/repos/Self/TestSDL/Window.cpp:14: undefined reference to` SDL_DestroyRenderer'
/usr/bin/ld: /mnt/c/users/nichorsin598/source/repos/Self/TestSDL/Window.cpp:15: undefined reference to `SDL_Quit' /mnt/c/users/nichorsin598/source/repos/Self/TestSDL/Window.cpp:19: undefined reference to` SDL_Init'
/usr/bin/ld: /mnt/c/users/nichorsin598/source/repos/Self/TestSDL/Window.cpp:23: undefined reference to `SDL_CreateWindow' /usr/bin/ld: /mnt/c/users/nichorsin598/source/repos/Self/TestSDL/Window.cpp:28: undefined reference to` SDL_CreateRenderer'
/usr/bin/ld: Instantiation.o: in function `Window::pollEvents()': /mnt/c/users/nichorsin598/source/repos/Self/TestSDL/Window.cpp:38: undefined reference to` SDL_PollEvent'
/usr/bin/ld: Instantiation.o: in function `Window::Clear() const': /mnt/c/users/nichorsin598/source/repos/Self/TestSDL/Window.cpp:72: undefined reference to` SDL_SetRenderDrawColor'
/usr/bin/ld: /mnt/c/users/nichorsin598/source/repos/Self/TestSDL/Window.cpp:73: undefined reference to `SDL_RenderClear' /usr/bin/ld: /mnt/c/users/nichorsin598/source/repos/Self/TestSDL/Window.cpp:81: undefined reference to` SDL_SetRenderDrawColor'
/usr/bin/ld: /mnt/c/users/nichorsin598/source/repos/Self/TestSDL/Window.cpp:82: undefined reference to `SDL_RenderFillRect' /usr/bin/ld: /mnt/c/users/nichorsin598/source/repos/Self/TestSDL/Window.cpp:88: undefined reference to` SDL_RenderPresent'

All the SDL things are undefined but I don't get an error saying SDL.h is undefined so it either has something to do with the libraries or something else
File Pathing is:
TestSDL- base directory
TestSDL\SDLDeps- includes the 2 folders include and lib
include- includes all .h files
lib- includes SDL2.dll, SDL2, SDL2Main, SDL2test
If anyone can help I'd be much obliged.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of different `SDL2` libraries for different components. I use [pkg-config](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pkg-config/) to get the compiling and linker flags a bit like this:

```
SDL2_INCS := $(shell pkg-config sdl2 --cflags) \
    $(shell pkg-config SDL2_image --cflags) \
    $(shell pkg-config SDL2_ttf --cflags) \
    $(shell pkg-config SDL2_net --cflags) \
    $(shell pkg-config SDL2_mixer --cflags)

SDL2_LIBS := $(shell pkg-config sdl2 --libs) \
    $(shell pkg-config SDL2_image --libs) \
    $(shell pkg-config SDL2_ttf --libs) \
    $(shell pkg-config SDL2_net --libs) \
    $(shell pkg-config SDL2_mixer --libs)

Instantiation.o: $(OBJS).cpp
    $(CC) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) $(SDL2_INCS) -o Instantiation.o $(SDL2_LIBS) $(OBJS).cpp
```

Comment: You should be able to pass several libs to a single `pkg-config` invocation.